# Ajax won't call Codeigniter controlllers's method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm total beginner to ajax (don't know jquery at all) so i've been using simple ajax without jquery, what i want to do is simple to call codeigniter's controller method. Dont know what i'm wrong at. Here's my ajax function and controller:

```
   function usernameOnChange() {
        var username = document.getElementById("register_username").value;
        if (username.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("usernameGlyph").className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";
            return;
        } else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("usernameGlyph").className  = 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok';
                }
            };
            var link = "<?php echo base_url("index.php/Test/checkUsername?username="); ?>" + username ;
            xmlhttp.open("GET", link, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

And here's my controller (it's still test controller just to see that my ajax-codeigniter php connection is working).

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->load->helper("security");
    $this->load->helper("form");
}

public function checkUsername($username) {
    echo "<script>alert('CODEIGNITER RESPONDED!');</scirpt>";
}

}

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here's solution that I've found out and it works fine. It changes icon-span of input field to tick if login username that is typed at the moment exists in database. Otherwise it changes icon to cross. Don't forget to add "&" when sending via "get" more than 1 parameter to controller's method.

```
$("#login_username").keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/Test/checkLoginUsername'; ?>',
        data: 'type=' + $('#logintype').is(':checked') + '&username=' + $("#login_username").val(),
        success: function(newClassType) {
            $("#usernameLoginGlyph").removeClass().addClass(newClassType);
        }
    })
});
```

Here's my controller method that echos result class type of icon.

```
public function checkLoginUsername() {
    // type = true for customer; false for artist
    $type = $this->input->get('type');
    $username = $this->input->get('username');
    if ($type === "true") {
        if ($username === "" || $this->Customer_model->getCustomerByUsername($username)) {
            echo "glyphicon glyphicon-ok";
        } else {
            echo "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";
        }
    } else {
        if ($username === "" || $this->Artist_model->getArtistByUsername($username)) {
            echo "glyphicon glyphicon-ok";
        } else {
            echo "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you start with ajax, need to understand that ajax required to have good output from the PHP to get perfect result of the call. In your codeigniter controller, you are echoing a script tag. Please dont do that when you use a ajax call.

**Sample Codeigniter Controller function**

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->load->helper("security");
    $this->load->helper("form");
}

public function checkUsername($username) {
    $output = array('status'=>200,"message"=>"Your Ajax is called");
    header('Content-Type:application/json;');//Please do not forgot to set headers
    echo json_encode($output);
}

}
```

Here the controller will give perfect output which javascript can read it easiliy

**For jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('<?php echo base_url("index.php/Test/checkUsername?username=xyz"); ?>',function(data){
    alert(data['message']);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as i said i'm total newbie in all this, can you help me out with this comment "//Please do not forgot to set headers" and what exactly i need to set up here, i thought it was only call php function, it will echo result and i should print it? Seems not simply as i thought? And by the way where i have specified that onclick ajax function will be invoked?

Comment: header(); is a function which defines the output format of the data, if you set it to "application/json" the javascript will easily understand the data and you can easily use it in your project

Comment: and what shaiful islam has given in answer is also true

Answer (score 1):

First of all your this line will produce error or unexpected result.

```
var link = "<?php echo base_url("index.php/Test/checkUsername?username="); ?>" + username ;
//double quote inside double quote
```

It should be like this

```
 var link = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Test/checkUsername?username='); ?>" + username ;
```

You also need to know how [`site_url`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url) and [base_url](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url) function produce links

Finally I think your link should be like this.

```
var link = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Test/checkUsername/'); ?>" + username ;
 //you can remove index.php if you set your config file properly.
```